# Launching jQuery plugins depending on the user location

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, client-side

My senior gave me a task to put all little javascript and jQuery plugin code in one file which will execute these plugins, depending if the page has certain .classes or #ids. I am thinking what is the best way to do that.

Will simple if -> else do in this case or should I go further and create something with .each?

I also think that with the growing amount of plugins and other client-side code, there will be significant performance issues. But so far we only have about 5-10 self-invoking functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really use what you want if you have a small amount of plugins to check.

If not then you should choose from this list: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/73

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It depends on how many elements it's going to have to cycle through. You could be more specific with span's, or div's if need be.

```
var a_i = 0, b_i = 0;

$("#ids").each(function() {
    a_i++;
});

$(".classes").each(function() {
    b_i++;
});

if(a_i != 0) {
    $.getScript("js/specific.plugin.min.js");
    $.executePluginFunctionNameThingyHere();
}

if(b_i != 0) {
    $.getScript("js/another-specific.plugin.min.js");
    $.executeOtherPluginFunctionNameThingyHere();
}
```

Not tested - but it's the general idea.

Comment: Not quite getting the idea of this. I increase the i depending on the number of ids I have specified, and then I fire all the scripts in the same time?